# Should a transaction be used in my case?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions

Here is a quote " So, if you are working with only one object context then you have already built-in support for database transactions when using the ObjectContext.SaveChanges method." I found here http://www.luisrocha.net/2011/08/managing-transactions-with-entity.html

So according to that, I don't have to use `TransactionScope` in a code below, right?

```
if (isLastCallSuccess)
 {
   if (condition1) //it's clear, no transaction needed
    {
      product.Property1 = true;
      context.SaveChanges();
    }

    else if (condition2)
     {
      using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) //do I need it?
      {
        context.DeleteObject(item);             //deleting
        context.AddObject("product", new product      //adding
                                {
                                    Id = oldObject.Id,
                                    Property1 = true
                                });
        context.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
                                scope.Complete();
        context.AcceptAllChanges();

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the quote means is that a single call to `SaveChanges` is automatically wrapped in a transaction, so it's atomic. You, however, are calling `SaveChanges` multiple times, so in order for the larger operation to be atomic you'll need to use the transaction as you currently have it.

So yes, you need it.

Comment: What would happen if I called context.SaveChanges) only one time? Did I need a transaction?

Comment: If you do it only once, then there's no need for the explicit transaction.

Comment: Can you tell me what's confusing you? `SaveChanges` always takes place within a transaction. If you batch all of your changes into a single call to `SaveChanges`, then that transaction will make all of your changes atomic. If you make changes, call `SaveChanges`, make more changes, then call `SaveChanges` again, then if you don't have an explicit outer transaction then the first call could succeed but the second one could fail, which would leave your database in the same state it was after you called `SaveChanges` the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally keep `TransactionScope` in so everything commits as a whole unit or rollsback upon an error (I.e. your save or add fails).  If concurrency is a major part of your application using this will benefit your users, ensuring the integrity of the data is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree; because you have multiple operations on your data, and you would want to make sure that the operations either succeed completely or fail completely (atomic). It also is good practice to make sure you are atomic.

If your delete worked, but your add failed, you would be left with a database in a bad state. At least if you had a transaction, the database would be back to the original state before you attempted the first operation.

EDIT:

Just for completion, inside a transaction, having the ability to rollback a transaction at any point is crucial, when you start to manipulate multiple tables in the same method/process.

Comment: " So, if you are working with only one object context then you have already built-in support for database transactions when using the ObjectContext.SaveChanges method." ?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it is built-in transaction support, it is implicit. Better to be explicit for readability. The two save changes are unnecessary and make the code a little less readable too.

Comment: Also, the type of transaction can be altered using TransactionScope, this would not be known if relying on some implicit logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your scenario you do need to use a transaction. `SaveChanges` creates an implicit transaction such that when it goes to persist a change to any of the objects, and that change cannot be persisted, it rolls back all other changes it attempted to make. But the transaction created by `SaveChanges` only lives as long as the call itself. If you are calling `SaveChanges` twice and want the actions of the first call to rollback if the second call fails, then yes, you need a transaction that wraps both calls, which the code you posted does just that.

Answer (score 0):

From how I am reading it, you are worried about the delete and adding not committing to the database and if there is a fail then rolling the transaction back.
I dont think you need to wrap your insert and delete in a transaction, because as mentioned above it is all happening on one savechanges() which implicitly has transaction management. so if it did fail the changes would be rolled back.